# How to convert .innerHTML to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps-api-3, innerhtml

hello friends I have a question I have this code that locates your coordinates
I WANT TO DO IS PASSING these coordinates to a variable PHP MYSQL TO INSERT IN SOMEONE HELP ME I COULD am new at this HERE I LEAVE MY CODE

---

```
<html>
<div id="mapa">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">




var divMapa = document.getElementById('mapa');
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fn_ok, fn_error);

function fn_error(){
divMapa.innerHTML='A PROBLEM PLEASE CONTACT ME!!!';
}

function fn_ok(respuesta){

var lat = respuesta.coords.latitude;
var lon = respuesta.coords.longitude;
divMapa.innerHTML = lat+' , '+lon;
}
</script>
<?php
$variablePHP = '<script> document.write(fn_ok()) </script>';
echo $variablePHP;
?>

</html>
```

---

THIS ONLY PRINT "undefined" in the php variable
hi from mexico`enter code here`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option would be to set a cookie through `JavaScript` and read it back with `PHP`.

**JavaScript**

Use the following function to make the cookie,

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();

        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

        var expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = '';
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/; domain=.example.com';
}
```

Don't forget to replace the `domain=[...]` URL part in the function.

**PHP**

```
echo $_COOKIE['YourCookieName'];
```

Alternatively you could use [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to pass your variable to `PHP`.